# The law of radioactive decay: explanation of a formula

Tags: radiation, radioactivity

The law of radioactive decay can be expressed in terms of $\,\tau=1/\lambda$ (average life) as:

$$
N(t)=N_0e^{-t/\tau}, \quad \tag{1}
$$

Why deriving the `(1)` I have:
\begin{equation}
N'(t)=N_0(1-e^{-\lambda t})\, ?
\end{equation}

Comment: Your second equation shouldn't be the starting point of the derivation. How did you get there?

Comment: I have some notes of a research that I'm elaborating. I have finded this without any linkage. I don't get it. If I derive the (1) I don't get the second one.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radioactive_decay#One-decay_process . 5 secs of Googling.

Comment: @Gert Could I please have a better explanation than Wikipedia, simpler and more complete? Actually, I haven't thought about searching on the web.

Comment: I don't think you'll find anything simpler (or more complete). It really is a very simple problem, you know?

Comment: @Gert If it were possible here for me, it would be better.

Comment: I think your N is the number of events remaining  at time t, and N' is the number that have decayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It comes from solving the differential equation

$$\frac{dN}{dt} = -\lambda N(t). $$

This equation comes from observations of the number of decay events $N(t)$. It's found through experiment that the rate of decay over a given time interval is proportional to the number of events recorded during that time. You can arrive at this conclusion by plotting the rate vs the number of events on a log log plot and finding that it is linear.

---

Formally, this is a differential equation. But solving it is really just a fact which you know already.

**Which function $N(t)$ can you take the derivative of and get itself back times a constant?**

The answer is exponentials, and so the solution to this equation is

$$
N(t) = N(0) e^{-\lambda t}.
$$

---

**Edit**:  I should also note that you took the derivative incorrectly. The correct derivative is

$$
N'(t) = \frac{d}{dt} N_0 e^{-\lambda t} = - \lambda N_0 e^{-\lambda t}
$$

Comment: *"the rate of decay is proportional to the the rate of these events"* That doesn't make a whole lot of sense. By your own formula (which is correct) the decay rate is proportional to the number of remaining atoms, macroscopically speaking at least.

Comment: oops.. made a typo thanks

Comment: @InertialObserver The derivative that I was founded is the same as your :-). My notes are probably wrong. In fact from the Wikipedia link provided by Gert: $N_{B}=N_{A_0}-N_A=N_{A_0}(1-e^{-\lambda t})$. Thank you very much for your answer.